# Jssor Slider On mac cant use Jssor.Compress.exe Any other way to compress?

Tags: jquery, macos, slider, jssor

I am using Jssor to create a slider on a mac. Stuck when trying to compress a no jQuery version because the app is .exe I need it to use the slider on ebay.

How do I use this .exe file?

Jssor.Compress.exe

I have looked at programs for opening windows files on mac but not sure if that's even the solution.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks